# Android ListView Custom Row Selection

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom row type that contains the following:

|Text|Spinner|

I have the row currently clickable on the spinner but not on the text. My problem is that if I used the built in keyboard D-Pad to browse the ListView then the entire row is highlighted when I only want it to highlight the Spinner. How do you handle the D-PAD in such a fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML file, locate the `Spinner` and add:

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Then disable focusing on the layout that contains them. For instance, if you have those side-by-side inside of a `LinearLayout`, then find the `LinearLayout` and add:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

It's also a good idea to ensure the text is focusable so that users with vision impairment can use a screen reader to hear the text read aloud.